# How to use callsite layout renderer with Sentinel log viewer?

Tags: c#, nlog, sentinel

I am using NLog in my one of the application and I am able to log the information in different targets like **File,Console,EventLog and also to NLogViewer.** 
I am using the layout as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<targets>
  <target name="event" xsi:type="EventLog" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${event-properties:EventID}" source="NLogDemo" />
  <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="C:\Users\sharathk\Desktop\ToCompare\${shortdate}LoggingDemo.txt" 
          layout="---------NLog File--------${newline}${longdate}=>${level}=>${message}=>${event-properties:EventID}=>${callsite:fileName=true:methodName=true}" />
  <target name="console"  xsi:type="Console" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${callsite:fileName=true}" />
  <target name="viewer" xsi:type="NLogViewer" layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}|${callsite:fileName=true}" address="udp://10.100.18.166:9999"/>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,console,viewer" />
</rules>
```

callSite property showing the right information in File, Console and EventLog but ***its not showing any information using callSite in Sentinel***
Please anybody help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Include something like this in your network target:

```
includeCallSite="true" includeSourceInfo="true"
```